# Having issues with a recursive program in C++

Tags: c++, recursion

I am following along with Stanford's CS106B course by myself. One of the assignments is asking for a recursive algorithm which will pull all brackets and braces out of a string that is provided to a function. I have attached below my code. I have managed to get the function to pull out all the brackets and braces. I have not managed to get it to return anything. It runs endlessly. I am wondering how to get it to stop without using a single loop or global variable. I've been trying this all day, seen many people's solutions for similar assignments, read the textbook, and have listened to the lectures many times yet I cannot get it to return anything.

Also: str.insert inserts a string into the position requested.

isalpha finds if the character in question is an alphabet in a string.

isdigit finds if the character in question is a digit in a string.

These are all functions provided in the Stanford libraries but I do not believe they are native to C++.

```
/*
 * TODO: remove and replace this file header comment
 * You will edit and turn in this file.
 * Remove starter comments and add your own
 * comments on each function and on complex code sections.
 */
#include <iostream>    // for cout, endl
#include <string>      // for string class
#include "recursion.h"
#include "testing/SimpleTest.h"

using namespace std;
//string strTemp;
/*
 * TODO: Replace this comment with a descriptive function
 * header comment.
 */
string operatorsFrom(string str) {
    string strTemp;//Not working because this is defined everytime
    /* TODO: Implement this function. */
   // str.insert(str.length(),"strTemp");
    if(!isalpha(str[0])&&!isdigit(str[0])){
        strTemp = str[0];
        str.insert(str.length(),strTemp);
        operatorsFrom(str.erase(0,1));
    }

    if(isalpha(str[0])||isdigit(str[0])){
        operatorsFrom(str.erase(0,1));
    }
    return str;
}

/*
 * TODO: Replace this comment with a descriptive function
 * header comment.
 */
bool operatorsAreMatched(string ops) {
    /* TODO: Implement this function. */
    return false;
}

/*
 * The isBalanced function assumes correct implementation of
 * the above two functions operatorsFrom and operatorsMatch.
 * It uses operatorsFrom to extract the operator characters
 * from the input string and then confirms that those
 * operators are balanced by using operatorsMatch.
 * You should not modify the provided code in the isBalanced
 * function.  If the previous two functions have been implemented
 * correctly, the provided isBalanced will correctly report whether
 * the input string has balanced bracketing operators.
 */
bool isBalanced(string str) {
    string ops = operatorsFrom(str);
    return operatorsAreMatched(ops);
}


/* * * * * * Test Cases * * * * * */

PROVIDED_TEST("operatorsFrom on simple example") {
    EXPECT_EQUAL(operatorsFrom("vec[3]"), "[]");
}

PROVIDED_TEST("operatorsAreMatched on simple example") {
    EXPECT(operatorsAreMatched("{}"));
}

PROVIDED_TEST("isBalanced on example from writeup") {
    string example ="int main() { int x = 2 * (vec[2] + 3); x = (1 + random()); }";
    EXPECT(isBalanced(example));
}

PROVIDED_TEST("isBalanced on non-balanced examples from writeup") {
    EXPECT(!isBalanced("( ( [ a ] )"));
    EXPECT(!isBalanced("3 ) ("));
    EXPECT(!isBalanced("{ ( x } y )"));
}
```

I have tried to get this function to return the parentheses, brackets, etc. It does manage to pull those out of text very well, but it gets stuck in the first if loop and does not return anything. So far I have tried to figure out some sort of counter, but that seems impossible without either a global variable or a loop of some sort, which are not allowed.

Edit: I have added the entire program. The function that is the issue is the string operatorsFrom function.

Comment: **does not return anything** Where is that point where you check the returned value?

Comment: @273K I used a debugger and it seems to just loop over and over again in the first if statement. I see the string I need, it just does not return it.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives. This allows other people to easily test your program, by simply using copy&paste.

Comment: When you call `operatorsFrom()` it returns a string, but your code never does anything with the string it returns, it just ignores the returned value.  That can't be correct.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Yes it doesn't do anything yet. I have not built that part yet because I cannot even get the operatorsFrom() to return anything.

Comment: @user112167 in order for a recursive function not to become an infinite regress, it has to reach a "base case" condition where it doesn't call itself.  In your function, what is the condition where `operatorsFrom()` doesn't call itself?  AFAICT if the first if-test doesn't succeed, then the second one will, so either way it always recurses.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I see! Thanks I think I will likely be able to solve the problem now. There is no base case condition here and it just loops infinitely. I did not understand from the lectures and text the importance of the base case. I will redesign the code so that there is one.